# How can I set-cookie on browser of mobile device?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, nestjs

I know there is have question like this, although I following so many answer, I still fix my problem. On computer, the cookie work perfectly, but on mobile it does not, I tried with Safari and Google Chrome.
This is server config

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule,{cors:{
    origin:isProduction ? process.env.CORS_PROD : process.env.CORS_DEV,
    credentials:true,
  }
});
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.setGlobalPrefix('finance/api')

  await app.listen(4444);
}
bootstrap();
```

And this function to set-cookie to browser . finance/api is prefix and /users/checkAuth is the route for authenticate user.

```js
async setCookie(userId: string, res: Response) {
    const refresh_token = await this.signToken(userId, 'refresh');
    res.cookie(this.config.get('COOKIE_NAME'), refresh_token, {

        httpOnly: true,
        secure: this.config.get('NODE_ENV') === 'production',
        sameSite: 'lax',
        path: 'finance/api/users/checkAuth',

    });
}
```

My client has a domain like **https://example.com**
My server has a domain like **https://example.com/finance/api**

Is this cause by cross-site domain or something ?

I tried to set secure option is false, and turn off Prevent Cross-Site Tracking, I'm also set credentials is true in client.
I hope understand what problem's kind happening and How can I fix it.

Comment: This is the same domain

Comment: So can you guest what kind of my problem?

Comment: Have you tried in the debug mode?  For iPhone/iPad connect to the Mac and check the Developer Tools in Safari. This helps to show the Network tab and see if cookies are coming from the server or if there are any issues, etc..